# How to check if a list of URLs exists

Tags: python

I'm trying to test if a simple list of urls exists, the code works when I'm just testing one url, but when I try add a array of urls, it's breaks.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

**Single URL Code**

```
import httplib
c = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.example.com')
c.request("HEAD", '')
if c.getresponse().status == 200:
   print('web site exists')
```

**Broken Array Code**

```
import httplib
Urls = ['www.google.ie', 'www.msn.com', 'www.fakeniallweb.com', 'www.wikipedia.org', 'www.galwaydxc.com', 'www.foxnews.com', 'www.blizzard.com', 'www.youtube.com']
for x in Urls:
    c = httplib.HTTPConnection(x)
    c.request("HEAD", '')
    if c.getresponse().status == 200:
        print('web site exists')
    else:
        print('web site' + x + 'un-reachable')

#To prevent code from closing
input ()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Also it's better if you use real variable names in SO as a courtesy to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dries De Rydt

Thanks for your help , it was a unresolved dns error causing it to crash out.

I ended up [Lib/socket.py](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname)

**solution**

```
import socket
Urls = ['www.google.ie', 'www.msn.com', 'www.fakeniallweb.com', 'www.wikipedia.org', 'www.galwaydxc.com', 'www.foxnews.com', 'www.blizzard.com', 'www.youtube.com']
for x in Urls:
    try:
        url = socket.gethostbyname(x)
        print x + ' was reachable '
    except socket.gaierror, err:
        print "cannot resolve hostname: ", x, err
#To prevent code from closing
input ()
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that you do it as an array, it is that one of your urls (www.fakeniallweb.com) has a different problem than your other urls.

I think because the DNS cannot be resolved, you cannot request the HEAD as you do. So you need an additional check other than just checking for response code 200.

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
try:
c.request("HEAD", '')
if c.getresponse().status == 200:
    print('web site exists')
else:
    print('website does not exist')
except gaierror as e:
    print('Error resolving DNS')
```

Honestly I suspect you will find other cases where a website returns different status codes. For example a website might return something in the 3xx range for a redirect, or a 403 if you cannot access it. That does not mean the website does not exist.

Hope this helps you on your way!